# Customizing the jointable column type of string lists in Grails domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've a domain class with a list of strings as one of many attributes.
Sometimes, the strings that are in the list have more than 255 chars. So,
how can I increase this limit in the database? Or change the column type for a CLOB or TEXT
type ??

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want to change the type o the column in the join table of your domain class. You can do this in the mapping of your `hasMany`, through the `type` option.

```
class Person {
  static hasMany = [nicknames: String]
  static mapping = { 
    hasMany joinTable: [
      name: 'bunch_o_nicknames', 
      key: 'person_id', 
      column: 'nickname', 
      type: "text"
    ]
  } 
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Marvo Maybe I missed what the OP wants, but I think the point is to change the type of the column in the join table of the hasMany, and that's what the example do.

Comment: Perhaps some explanation in your answer would help?  (My comment above was a canned response provided by the reviewer feature.)